# Add dash in list of weekdays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sequence:

```
WEEKDAYS = [
    'Sun',
    'Mon',
    'Tue',
    'Wed',
    'Thu',
    'Fri',
    'Sat',
]
```

There are inputs like:

```
['Sun', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
```

And I want output like:

```
Sun, Thu - Sat
```

I am very confused how to do it.

Comment: please explain how inputs are derived

Comment: More simply, I mean maybe: i have `mylist = [0, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. 5 to 8 is a sequential number whereas 0 with 6 is not, so the output is like `0, 5-8`.

Comment: Do you want the ranges to wrap around?  E.g., should the input `['Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']` produce the output `Fri - Sun`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). The items from the input list are clustered based on their distribution in the `WEEKDAYS` by grouping those with an index difference of 1:

```
from itertools import count, groupby

lst = ['Sun', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
c = count()
new_lst = []
for _, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: WEEKDAYS.index(x)-next(c)):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) > 2:
        new_lst.append(g[0] + '-' + g[-1])
    else:
        new_lst.extend(g)
print(new_lst)
# ['Sun', 'Thu-Sat']
```

You can make list `WEEKDAYS` a dictionary if you need to avoid multiple `list.index` calls as in the current approach.